# Can I replace "that" with "how"?

Tags: grammar

> Love, family and relationships only feature in policy debates about how we live to the extent **that** they concern children’s lives.

In my understanding，the sentence trunk might be "Love, family and relationships only feature in policy debates to the extent"，am I right？And can I replace "that" with "how"?

Comment: No. "That" is a subordinator here whereas "how" is an adverb, In some informal contexts "how" can replace "that", as in "Ed told him how/that his cattle had been rustled", but it's not possible in your example.

Comment: [to the extent that](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/to-the-extent-that) is an idiom.

Answer (score 0):

The main sentence is:

> Love, family and relationships only feature in policy debates

And "**that**" definitely should not be replaced with "**how**". If you do, the resulting sentence will be ungrammatical and possibly not clearly understandable.